# Is there a way to "cast" an array to (object) as a property of class/trait?

Tags: php, php-5.6

In PHP, I like the ability to declare objects (new instances of the stdClass) in one step like so:

`$obj = (object) ['a','b','c'];`

This works great.. *but* as a class property:

```
class Foo {
    public $obj = (object) ['a','b','c'];
}
```

I get the following error:

> syntax error, unexpected '(object)' (object) (T_OBJECT_CAST)

Is there another way to accomplish this? And, does anyone know why the above code is disallowed (perhaps specific to php 5.6)? I couldn't find specific documentation anywhere.

Comment: Did you tried to cast it inside the Constructor and assign it to attribute?

Comment: i don't think that you can use the json notation in php, at least as I know, i don't know if in newer version this notation has been added. Then if you wanna cast to an object i think you should turn that array into an assoc array

Comment: Specifically with traits, the one-liner casting approach is very convenient since there's no other one-full-swoop way to define and set an object like that (AFAIK). And since implementing a constructor coupled with a trait is straight bad news, I'll have to live with an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting from the [PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php):

> They [object properties] are defined by using one of the keywords public, protected, or private, followed by a normal variable declaration. This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization **must be a constant value** -- that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and **must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated**.

(my emphasis)

And

```
public $obj = (object) ['a','b','c'];
```

is dependent on `run-time` information, namely run-time casting of array to object

The way to get round this is to assign the value in the constructor

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and the link! (to where I completely missed that bit earlier) My particular use is inside of a trait so unfortunately a constructor assignment is a no go for me.